# MongoDB - $push accumulator is slowing query down

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

To develop a web application, I use MongooDB as Back-End and I need to retrieve data from it. On a particular page I need to recover prices' history from specific brands. In my MongoDB collection, here is how a document/product is saved :

```
{
  brand : "exampleBrand"
  prices : Array
    0: Object
      date "2022-03-08"
      price: 1900
    1: Object
      date "2022-03-09"
      price: 1910
}
```

My goal is then to retieve dates and prices from a specific brand in the following format :

```
{
  {
   date : "2022-03-08",
   prices : [price_product1, priceproduct2,...]
  }
  {
   date : "2022-03-09",
   prices : [price_product1, priceproduct3,...]
  }
}
```

In order to do that I have designed the following query :

```
db.Prices.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          {brand: "exampleBrand"}],
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          prices: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$prices',
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$prices.date",
          prix: {
            $push: "$prices.price",
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Once I have these results I can go on with different calculations etc... to display on my page. However, there are approcimatively 90000 documents, each of them having in average 30 prices and dates. Thus, the group stage of the aggregation pipeline is taking a long time.

I have try different indexes on "prices", "prices.date", "brand, prices" but none of them seem to speed up the query. I have also tried twisting and changing the query but couldn't find a more efficient way to get my results. Would anyone have an idea on how to achieve this ?

Thank you,

Comment: You could consider creating a [materialized view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/). This can work well if this collection doesn't change very often or if you don't need completely up-to-date results.

Comment: Where is `product` (eg from `price_product1`) present in the original document? To confirm, you are attempting to combine multiple existing documents together as opposed to simply reshaping the existing documents?

Comment: Have you examined the [`explain`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation) information?

Answer (score 0):

For faster querying here with these conditions I think the only way is to use mechanisms like `Redis` or `Memcached` because the query, especially in the array, would cost a lot of io and process for the aggregation process.

> P.S. I doubt that but if you somehow are able to change your data structure in a way that it would be flat it would be faster but not like caching method faster.

example:

```
{
  brand : "exampleBrand"
  price1 :  1900
  date1 : "2022-03-08"
  price2 :  2100
  date2 : "2022-03-29"
}
```

Comment: I will have a look at Redis or Memcached, as for your example, I don’t see how that would work because I would not be able to know easily which price corresponds to a specific date

Comment: @BastienB. Yeah because it's nearly impossible right? Because of that i said "doubt that". And it will work if your aggregation pipeline doesn't have to deal with arrays but juat one field it's because that  the unwind operation has to breakdown the arrays and create more objects corresponding to your arrays of prices and then you have to group them again! and also working with arrays in JS is a slow process it self. But I would say caching is the best solution here. Also if you think  my answer is good enough help others by voting up and mark it as an answer please.